# const* const in method argument

Tags: c++, syntax, constants

What do the 2 consts in the following function definition's argument imply?

```
void myFunction (MyClass* const* const myObj);
```

Comment: It's a pointer that can't be modified to a pointer that can't be modified to a `MyClass`, I'm guessing.

Comment: @minitech, Almost, it's a constant pointer to a constant pointer to a non-constant thing.

Comment: @chris: Heh, that's actually what I meant, but I mangled the sentence. Is the new one right?

Comment: Always disliked the syntax for this.

Comment: @minitech, Yes, it is :)

Comment: @Troy, Check out the spiral rule. It's a good mnemonic for type declarations. The other option for C declarations if you have the internet handy is cdecl.org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read it from right to left:

```
MyClass* const* const
   ^   ^   ^  ^ ^
   |   |   |  | 1
   |   |   |  |
   |   |   |  2
   |   |   3
   |   4
   5
```

A *(1)* **const** *(2)* **pointer** to a *(3)* **const** *(4)* **pointer** to `MyClass`. In other words, you cannot change the pointers, but the `MyClass` instance remains mutable.

Answer (score 1):

The argument is a pointer to pointer to object.

The first `const` means that the indirect pointer (the one accessed as `*myObj`) cannot be changed.

The second `const` means nothing useful, as `myObj` is passed by value and it's pointless to make a function's local copy of an argument be `const`.